# Detecting changes for several companies

Tags: r

I wonder if anyone can provide me with some tools/packages/codes to detect changes in the peer groups that are used for relative performance evaluation.

I have a dataframe with all peers that are used for a certain firm (CIK) over the years. An example of this data is given below:

```
CIK <- c("21344","21344", "21344", "21344", "21344", "21344", "21344", "21344", "21344")
FiscalYear <- c("2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017")
PeerCIK <- c("1800","1800","1800","1800","1800","21456","21456","21456","21456")
dataframe <- data.frame(CIK, FiscalYear, PeerCIK)
```

This results in the following table:

```
    CIK FiscalYear PeerCIK
1 21344       2013    1800
2 21344       2014    1800
3 21344       2015    1800
4 21344       2016    1800
5 21344       2017    1800
6 21344       2014   21456
7 21344       2015   21456
8 21344       2016   21456
9 21344       2017   21456
```

Now, I want to identify whether the peers (`PeerCIK`) are present for the whole period that is covered by the firm (`CIK`). I thus first need to identify the first and last year per `CIK` (in this example it is clear (2013-2017), but I need to do this for many firms). A code I used for this is:

```
df2 <- dataframe %>%
    group_by(CIK) %>% 
    summarise(
        start = min(FiscalYear), 
        end = max(FiscalYear)
    )
```

```
> df2
    CIK start  end
1 21344  2013 2017
```

and following I need to identify whether all different peers are present for that period.
If this is not true, then a change must have taken place in the peer group (the peer is added to or deleted from the group). This is where I have trouble with how to continue. The outcome that I ultimately want, is a dataframe with for every firm (CIK), per fiscalyear whether a change has taken place in the peer group compared to last year (where change is a dummy variable with value 1 if change takes place). Such a change is thus when a peer is added (after the starting date) or when a peer is no longer included while the end date is not yet reached for that particular CIK.

## Expected outcome

For the example above, I would have the following outcome, as company 21456 is added from 2014 onwards and thus a change has taken place compared to 2013:

```
    CIK FiscalYear change
1 21344       2013      0
2 21344       2014      1
3 21344       2015      0
4 21344       2016      0
5 21344       2017      0
```

I really hope someone can help me, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different approach via `expand()`, `full_join`, and some helper variables which should cover most of your edge cases:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dataframe %>%
    # Add helper variable to indicate present relationships.
    mutate(
        present = 1
    ) %>%
    # Generate all possible variations of CIK, FiscalYear, and PeerCik
    # and join with our data.
    full_join(
        dataframe %>% expand(CIK, FiscalYear, PeerCIK),
        by = c("CIK", "FiscalYear", "PeerCIK")
    ) %>%
    # Set the helper variable to 0 wherever it is missing,
    # which is the case in your newly joined empty data from `expand(...)`.
    mutate(
        present = ifelse(is.na(present), 0, present)
    ) %>%
    # Sort the data because now the order will be important.
    arrange(CIK, PeerCIK, FiscalYear) %>%
    # Group by CIK-PeerCIK relationship...
    group_by(
        CIK, PeerCIK
    ) %>%
    # ...and compare each FiscalYear to the previous FiscalYear. 
    mutate(
        # Check if a relationship was added compared to the year before.
        added = case_when(
            row_number() == 1 ~ 0,
            lag(present) == 0 & present == 1 ~ 1, 
            TRUE ~ 0
        ),
        # Check if a relationship was removed compared to the year before.
        removed = case_when(
            row_number() == 1 ~ 0,
            lag(present) == 1 & present == 0 ~ 1, 
            TRUE ~ 0
        ),
        # Combine those two into one variable.
        change = ifelse(abs(added) + abs(removed) > 0, 1, 0)
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    # Now to the summary: Group by CIK and FiscalYear...
    group_by(
        CIK, FiscalYear
    ) %>%
    # ...and calculate all sums for each CIK and FiscalYear.
    summarize(
        # Total number of present relationships in this year.
        num_present = sum(present),
        # Number of added relationships in this year.
        num_added = sum(added),
        # Number of removed relationships in this year.
        num_removed = sum(removed),
        # Was there any change in this year?
        # An alternative would be `sum(change)` to
        # indicate the number of changed relationships.
        change = max(change)
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
```

**Result:**

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 6
  CIK   FiscalYear num_present num_added num_removed change
  <chr> <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>
1 21344 2013                 1         0           0      0
2 21344 2014                 2         1           0      1
3 21344 2015                 2         0           0      0
4 21344 2016                 2         0           0      0
5 21344 2017                 2         0           0      0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This had been of huge help (:

Comment: @Lisette Happy to help. :-) Just as a reminder: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)